# WordPress - How to delete ton of spam comments?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is there a way to delete 2,260 spam comments all together? Deleting all that spam comment by comment would take me a month or so.

Comment: find a pattern and use it

Comment: what is a pattern? if u have one .. will be more than appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that site you gave me the address to solved the problem. The site contained the only command I needed.

```
"DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = 'spam'"
```

That's all it needed. Thank you very much for your help. If it wasn't for you posting that link, I probably would of given up

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way how you can do it directly from the Admin UI:

**Step 1:** Goto to the admin page: `wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=spam`.

**Step 2:** There you can change the number of displayed comments in your *Screen Options* to your needs:

[image: Spam]

**Step 3:** Then you can select all authors and use the bulk action *Delete Permanently* :

[image: delete spam]

*Notice:* You might need to find the suitable number of comments to delete in each turn. 
Selecting too many might give you timeout.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query with **caution**,

```
DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = 'spam'
```